# XML Parsing Child Elements using xml.etree.ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, parsing

I'm trying to get return all UK artists in alphabetical order--I'm not fully understanding XML parsing. What I've gathered from debugging and the documentation is that when you use the findall() method it returns a list that cannot be further navigated, is this correct? So how do I iterate over the subelements of a parent node, in this case `<cd>`, to find all of the elements whose country=='UK'? Thanks in advance!

```
def get_uk_artists(xmlstr):
      xml = ET.fromstring(xmlstr)
      artist_list = []
      for each in xml.findall('cd'):
          if each.findall('./cd/country').text == 'UK':
              artist_list.append(each.findall('artist').text)
      return artist_list.sort()
```

The XML is:

```
 xml_doc ='''<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
    <catalog>
        <cd>
            <title>Empire Burlesque</title>
            <artist sex="male">Bob Dylan</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>Columbia</company>
            <price>10.90</price>
            <year>1985</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Hide your heart</title>
            <artist sex="female">Bonnie Tyler</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>CBS Records</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1988</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Greatest Hits</title>
            <artist sex="female">Dolly Parton</artist>
            <country>USA</country>
            <company>RCA</company>
            <price>9.90</price>
            <year>1982</year>
        </cd>
        <cd>
            <title>Still got the blues</title>
            <artist sex="male">Gary Moore</artist>
            <country>UK</country>
            <company>Virgin records</company>
            <price>10.20</price>
            <year>1990</year>
        </cd>
    </catalog>
    '''
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ET.fromstring(xml_doc)
artists = []
for cd in xml.findall('cd'):
    if cd.find('country').text == 'UK':
        artists.append(cd.find('artist').text)

artists.sort()
print(artists)
```

**Output**

```
['Bonnie Tyler', 'Gary Moore']
```

This loops over each `cd` in the document. If the `cd` has a `country` child element with text equal to `'UK'`, the `cd` artist name gets appended to the list of artists. `artists.sort()` then sorts the list in-place.

Comment: Thanks @lambo477 --it did the trick! I have a couple questions: 1. I tried artists.sort(), but it returned an empty list. However sorted(artists) worked, any ideas why this is? 2. When we call the findall() method, what structure does it return?

Comment: `artists.sort()` will return `None`, but it sorts the list 'in-place'. Run `print(artists)` and you will see the sorted list. To use `sorted()` returns a list, so you would need to use `artists = sorted(artists)`.

Comment: `xml.findall()` returns a list of elements